# Commutative von Neumann regular ring with more than two prime ideals.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

> Is there an example of commutative von Neumann regular ring which has more than 2 prime ideals?

Matrix rings are not commutative so I couldn't find any, please help.

Comment: If $F$ is a field, the product ring  $F^n$ is commutative, VNR with $n$ maximal ideals.

Comment: Why  downvotes? The reason why I didn't give anything , is Idk commutative algebra, i just begin that

Comment: "just began" and already on von Neumann regular rings huh.  Not a great sequencing :)

Comment: @rschwieb, yes true it's not great sequencing,  but I somehow got interested in that (I'm not studying von Neumann ring btw). So I think it might not be a problem. Or is it?

Comment: Looking for examples of VNR rings looks a lot like you are studying them, at least, temporarily.

Comment: @rschwieb , you are right, I am gonna take commutative algebra course upcoming semester  but because of some reason I have to look at VNR now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known  that the quotient of a commutative ring by is nilradical is *absolutely flat* if and only if every prime ideal is maximal(Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. II *Localisation*, §4, exercise 16 d) – in other words, a reduced ring is absolutely flat if and only if it has Krull dimension $0$.

Therefore a product of more than $2$ copies of a field provides such an example.